# Knockout observableArray not updating with multiple view models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have multiple view models contained in one master view model. I am trying to insert an item into an array in viewmodel A from viewmodel B. In my log I see the item getting added to the array but it is not updating the UI.

http://jsfiddle.net/U7rXA/

-----HTML

```
    <form data-bind="submit: RolesVM.addRole">
    <select name="app" data-bind="options:ApplicationsVM.applications,optionsText:'name', value: RolesVM.application"><option></option></select></td>
    <input data-bind='value: RolesVM.role, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"'/> 
    <button>Add Role</button>
</form>

<ul data-bind="foreach: ApplicationsVM.applications">
    <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: roles">
        <li data-bind="text:name"></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

-----JS

```
        function MasterVM(applicationsVM, rolesVM) {
        this.ApplicationsVM = applicationsVM;
        this.RolesVM = rolesVM;
    }
    function ApplicationsVM() {
        var self = this;
        self.applications = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.Populate = function () {
            var allData = jQuery.parseJSON('[{ "name": "app 1", "roles": [{ "name": "role 1" }] }, { "name": "app 2", "roles": [{ "name": "role 1" }] }]');
            var mappedApplications = $.map(allData, function (item) {return new Application(item);});
            self.applications(mappedApplications);
        };
    }
    function RolesVM() {
        var self = this;
        self.application = ko.observable();
        self.role = ko.observable();

        self.addRole = function () {
            self.application().roles().push(self.role());
            console.log(self.application().roles());
        };
    }

    function Application(data) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.roles = ko.observableArray($.map(data.roles, function(item) { return new Role(item.name); }));
    }

    function Role(data) {
        this.name = data;
    }

    var applicationsVM = new ApplicationsVM();
    applicationsVM.Populate();
    var rolesVM = new RolesVM();
    ko.applyBindings(new MasterVM(applicationsVM, rolesVM));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to call `push` on the observableArray directly and not the underlying array.  This is what notifies any subscribers that it has changed.  So, you would wan to do:

```
self.application().roles.push(self.role());
```

rather than:

```
self.application().roles().push(self.role());
```

Comment: That updates my UI but the item comes back as 'result' no matter what I type. http://jsfiddle.net/SBkxw/

Comment: Ah I needed to set it as a role instead of just the string value for name..

  var role = new Role(self.role());
  self.application().roles.push(role);

Comment: This is an important point, thanks helped resolve my issue!
I removed the () and it resolved. I am using like this ko.utils.arrayPushAll(arr, itemModels);